# WebForm Date Field

Tags: javascript, c#, html, date, webforms

I am creating a form and not finding how to populate a date field with the calendar date.  The form should populate the date when a new form is created.  I have the following code:

```html
<div>
  <label><b>Request Initiation Date</b></label><br />
  <input type="date" id="RequestDate">
  <script>
    (function() {
      var date = new Date().toISOString().substring(0, 10);
      var field = document.querySelector('#Requestate');
      field.value = date;
      console.log(field.value);
    });
  </script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below-given js -

```
document.getElementById("RequestDate").valueAsDate = new Date()
```

The new Date() fn will get the current date and assign it to the target input[type=date] control.

Comment: Thank You!  That worked and was more straightforward than anything else I have tried today.

Comment: A good answer should explain why the OP has their issue and how to fix it. This does neither.

Answer (score 0):

You have two issues. Firstly, in

```
document.querySelector('#Requestate')
```

you have mistyped the element ID, it should be

```
document.querySelector('#RequestDate')
--------------------------------^
```

Secondly, you aren't calling the function, so the last line should be:

```
    }());
-----^^
```

The full code:

```html
<div>
  <label><b>Request Initiation Date</b></label><br />
  <input type="date" id="RequestDate">
  <script>
    (function() {
      var date = new Date().toISOString().substring(0, 10);
      var field = document.querySelector('#RequestDate');
      field.value = date;
      console.log(field.value);
    }());
  </script>
</div>
```

Of course you can write it in less code, but you should consider readability and maintainability before doing that.

Comment: I used the following code to populate the date field:
            <script>
                document.getElementById("RequestDate").valueAsDate = new Date();
            </script>

Comment: @Pens_Cup87—that doesn't work in browsers that don't support input type date or *valueAsDate*. Your original code, with the minor changes suggested, does. However, your original code use *toISOString*, which might return the wrong date depending on the time and host timezone offset so you should use a different method for formatting the date string.